# Using Set still showing duplicates

Tags: apex

I'm have a list of records with duplicates. To remove duplicates I'm adding the values of List to Set but the Set is still having duplicates.

Code snippet:

```
customField__c = '2022/2023, 2023/2024, 2024/2025';

List<String> delyears;
delyears = (customField__c).split('/');
System.debug('reldelyears:::'+ delyears);
Set<String> noDups = new Set<String>(delyears);
System.debug('noDups:::'+ noDups);
```

[image]

Am I missing something or any other way to remove duplicates for the list, please suggest.

Comment: Those are not duplicates. You have comma separated parts of the strings you are not splitting out. The output is misleading because some commas from from the data, not the debug formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to work, swap out the commas and then run the split.

```
String field = '2022/2023, 2023/2024, 2024/2025';
field = field.replaceAll(', ','/');
List<String> delyears = field.split('/');
Set<String> noDups = new Set<String>(delyears);
System.debug('noDups:::'+ noDups);
```

Note, I'm taking the space into account in the replace.

To optimize, just assign the split as the param to the set constructor:

```
String replaced = customField__c.replaceAll(', ','/');
Set<String> noDups = new Set<String>(replaced.split('/'));
```

For completeness sake, I was also working on a regex, which looks like this:

```
field.split('/|,\\s*')
```

Answer (score 4):

As Phil W said, the commas in your starting string are muddying the waters here.

If you were to loop over `delyears` and print out each individual string, you'd see

```
'2022'
'2023, 2023'
'2024, 2024'
'2025'
```

If you split on the commas as well, you'd be closer but the space would still muck things up (you'd have `'2023'` as well as `' 2023'`).

`String.split()` takes a regex, so as long as you understand *precisely* what you're looking to split on it's usually a pretty easy regex.

```java
// Split on forward slashes, OR a comma followed by a space
// Will result in ['2022', '2023', '2023', '2024', '2024', '2025']
List<String> delyears = customField__c.split('/|(,\\s)');

// Will contain ['2022', '2023', '2024', '2025']
Set<String> noDups = new Set<String>(delyears);
```